# how to take the difference between dates like "30MAY07"?

Tags: r, datetime

In R, how can I  convert time variable "30MAY07" or "21AUG09" to a value? I want to find the time difference between them. Thanks!

Comment: `as.Date("30MAY07", '%d%b%y')- as.Date('21AUG09', '%d%b%y')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lubridate` package for this:

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(c('30MAY07', '21AUG09'))
# [1] "2007-05-30 UTC" "2009-08-21 UTC"
```

`strftime` and `as.Date` from base R are also good options, but lubridate make very good informed guesses as to the format of the date. You see in your example, there is no need to specify anything else than to use the day month year function (`dmy`) and things work out of the box.